# Weren't Dor Hamidbar exempt from all Mitzvos as "already sentenced to death"?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, mitzvah, capital-punishment, dor-hamidbar

IIRC, one who was sentenced to death is considered already dead (גברא קטילא)<sup>(San 85a, but exact source needed)</sup> (or is it only about losing his property?).

When G-d sentenced all 20-60 y.o. Jews to die in the wilderness:  ([Num 17,29](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.14.29?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0)):

> **בַּמִּדְבָּר הַזֶּה יִפְּלוּ פִגְרֵיכֶם** וְכָל־פְּקֻדֵיכֶם לְכָל־מִסְפַּרְכֶם מִבֶּן עֶשְׂרִים שָׁנָה וָמָעְלָה אֲשֶׁר הֲלִינֹתֶם עָלָי׃
>
> **In this very wilderness shall your carcasses drop**. Of all of you who were recorded in your various lists from the age of twenty years up, you who have muttered against Me

Shouldn't it automatically exempt them all from all Mitzvos as already dead? Or, because the generation was sentenced by G-d it has a different status?

---

*If you have a source that my assumption is wrong, please let me know, I'll delete the question, don't just downvote.*

Comment: It’s not a death sentence at all, it was just a decree that they wouldn’t reach Israel

Comment: Also following your logic as soon as a baby is born he’s destined to die so why should he fulfill the Mitzvos?l

Comment: @Lages I said sentenced, no baby is not sentenced to die any moment. It wasn't a Halacha to decree it was their judgment and death sentence.

Comment: @Lages Your assumption is incorrect. See Bemidbar 26:65 that explicitly says that G-d had told them that they would die in the desert.

Comment: Well, it seems that someone downvoted, but may not have explained why. (It wasn't me.) 2 things, Al: 1) I don't know if that's the correct halacha. It needs a source to back that. 2) In many places throughout the Talmud, esp. Pirkei Avot, we learn that the reward for mitzvah performance is in *olam haba*. (Of course, there is some reward in this world, as well.) So, with that concept in mind, it would be contradictory to state that you are exempt from all mitzvoth once you have been sentenced to death.

Comment: @DanF Right, so I just asked a separate question on that, can we put this one on hold?

Comment: I think best you can do is delete this question. Before doing that, you may want to copy its URL, as it's a bit tricky to find a deleted question. Later, you can undelete it and edit it.

Comment: I think the source you’re thinking of -re. dead man walking- is San. 85a

Comment: @Oliver Very thanks, I added it to the question.

Comment: @Salmononius2 Even if we prove the assumption right, there might be tons of reasons why D"H was different and was obligated in Mitzvos, otherwise why would the TOrah tell all the stories.

Comment: @Salmononius2 I do not see an answer to that question. As a result, both should stay open until one of them gets an valid answer. After that, the unanswered one should be marked a duplicate.